# Whether every router in a AS must have its RouterID?

Tags: routing, router

Whether every router in a AS must have its RouterID?

I know if a AS want to use BGP, the routers in the AS must have its own RouterID.

whether a AS want to use router protocol, the routers must have a RouetrID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the routing protocol. For example, every OSPF router will have a router ID, but RIP doesn't use router IDs, it uses the interface address of the directly connected interface.

Routers that do not use a routing protocol (statically configured, or only route between directly connected networks) to exchange routes will not have a router ID.

Comment: how about EIGRP and IS-IS?

Comment: I was referring to the commonly used open standard routing protocols. IS-IS uses something else (Network Entity Title). EIGRP uses a router ID.